# Exclude three ranges from a protection

Tags: google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I made this code below but I can't exclude 3 intervals from Total protection, what can I do?

I have tried this:

```
async function creaFoglio() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var nomeDip = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue()
  var mail = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2).getValue()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("creare")
  await sheet.setName(nomeDip)
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(nomeDip)
  let me = Session.getEffectiveUser()
  let protecionFoglioTotale = sheet.protect()
  let intervallo1 = sheet.getRange('C7:C34').protect()
  let intervallo2 = sheet.getRange('I7:I34').protect()
  let intervallo3 = sheet.getRange('H2').protect()
  
  var editorDaRimuovere = ss.getEditors().map(function(editor) {
    return editor.getEmail();
  });
  
  // Rimuovi tutti gli editor dagli intervalli protetti
  protecionFoglioTotale.removeEditors(editorDaRimuovere);
  intervallo1.removeEditors(editorDaRimuovere);
  intervallo2.removeEditors(editorDaRimuovere);
  intervallo3.removeEditors(editorDaRimuovere);
  
  // Aggiungi te e l'indirizzo email specificato come editor
  protecionFoglioTotale.addEditors([me.getEmail()]);
  intervallo1.addEditors([me.getEmail(), mail]);
  intervallo2.addEditors([me.getEmail(), mail]);
  intervallo3.addEditors([me.getEmail(), mail]);

  ss.toast("Foglio creato e protezioni settate", "Foglio creato")
}
```

What I would like to achieve is the exclusion of the 1,2,3 ranges from the global protection

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `exclude 3 intervals from Total protection`. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.